# repo sync fails with "error: index-pack died of signal 9"

Tags: android, git, github

I am trying to sync with the Android sources repo and getting an error:

> error: index-pack died of signal 9
>   error: index-pack died
>   remote: Sending approximately 2.01 GiB ...
>   remote: Counting objects: 1, done
>   remote: Finding sources: 100% (20881/20881)
>   Receiving objects: 100% (20881/20881), 2.00 GiB | 6.11 MiB/s, done.
>
> remote: Total 20881 (delta 14047), reused 20831 (delta 14047)
>
> error: index-pack died of signal 9)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

9 is defined to be `SIGKILL` (see the `signal(7)` manual page), so I suspect you do this on a 32-bit Linux system and possibly [the OOM-killer](http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/) kicks in — your could verify this looking at the `dmesg` output or reading `/var/log/system` or `/var/log/messages`.

To combat this, try playing with the `core.packedGitWindowSize` and `core.packedGitLimit` [configuration variables](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).