# Git error: "rev-list died of signal 9" and "index-pack died of signal 9"

Tags: git

Since a few days ago, when trying to run `git pull` on a production server which has been working fine for the last several months, I am getting the following error:

```
error: rev-list died of signal 9
remote: Counting objects: 1487, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (333/333), done.
remote: Total 1340 (delta 952), reused 1340 (delta 952)
Receiving objects: 100% (1340/1340), 59.51 MiB | 26.78 MiB/s, done.
error: index-pack died of signal 9 
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The server is Ubuntu 12.04 and the git version is 1.7.9.5.

I have found similar questions on Stack Overflow ( [repo sync fails with "error: index-pack died of signal 9"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360393/repo-sync-error-index-pack-died-of-signal-9) and [Repack of Git repository fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826639/repack-of-git-repository-fails) ) but I am not sure if their answers could also apply to my case and I don't want to mess it up even more.

Any help with this, please?

Comment: Yes, it's the OOM killer, exactly as described in the other article.  Note that everything is fine on the remote (it's not "remote: ... signal 9" that you're seeing, all the "signal 9" stuff is on your *local* machine) so it's your *local* system that is out of memory.  Find out why, add memory or swap space if needed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was using capifony, symfony2 and a digital ocean droplet with ubuntu. It turns that my server disk space was too low, when the droplet was resized to 2gb ram and 40gb in disk everything worked fine again.